# add an object declared on the controller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am an angularJS beginner and i have an issue.
I want to add data to a media-object in html using an object declared in the script inside the controller, but i can't find which directive i must use.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dishCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                      <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}<span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span><span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span></h4>
                    <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                <p>Put the comments here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);

        app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

            var dish = {
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains',
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }

                           ]
                    };

            this.dish = dish;

        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Could someone help me? I think it's something easy but know I have collapsed!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least 2 options.

Option 1: Use $scope. This will make sure your html remains unchanged

```
app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {
   // Your dish declaration
   $scope.dish = dish;
 });
```

Option 2: Javascript remains unchanged. In HTML, prefix dish with dishCtrl since you use `dishDetailController as dishCtrl`

Ex: Instead of `<img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">`, use

```
<img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dishCtrl.dish.image}} alt="Uthapizza">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it goes. i thought i have done it at some time, but may be i got confused with the code. it was easy. Thank you so much

Comment: Yeah. I can understand. With time it will be even more easier for you...

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you're after, however I'm assuming that you just want to know how to change/update data inside the controller, and have it reflect inside the view?

Anything you add into your `dish` object, will be accessible under the dish property inside your html inside angularjs expressions.

Example:

```
app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {
    this.dish = {
        colour : 'blue'
    };
});
```

Then inside your view/html:

```
<div ng-controller="dishDetailController">
    {{dish.colour}}
</div>
```

If you're trying to use the comments as that is the only thing I could see that you have not implemented yet.

Inside your html you can do something like this:

```
<ul class="comments">
    <li class="comment" ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments">
        {{comment.comment}} - Author ({{comment.author}}) Rating : {{comment.rating}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I see what your issue is, sorry, you need to prefix everything with `dishCtrl`